# Cocos2d x How to create CCMenuItemImage with texture packer

Tags: cocos2d-x, texturepacker

I'm using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)  to pack my sprites.
Then I'm trying to use it but I have no idea that how to create CCMenuImageItem with that sprite sheet.
Cause CCMenuImageItem::create has defined as:

```
CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::itemWithNormalImage(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage)

CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::create(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage)

CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::itemWithNormalImage(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)

CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::create(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)

CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::itemWithNormalImage(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, const char *disabledImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)

CCMenuItemImage * CCMenuItemImage::create(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, const char *disabledImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use TexturePacker, you will get a plist file.
Then in your code, you should load your resources first.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("yourTexture.plist");
```

And then, read the ressource from the file

```
CCMenuItemImage * item = CCMenuItemImage::itemWithNormalImage(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage);
```

Hope it will be helpful :).

Comment: Thanks Spencer Wong,
I found that I can you CCMenuItemSprite, and add sprites get from plist.
Any way, thank for your answer